# multiple text inputs need onfocus to show multiple div

Tags: jquery, forms, html, input

Thanks for looking at my question. Basically what is going on, I have several (12) input fields (id="editname") and the divs (id="iconbar") on 1 page. I would like the icon bar to slide in when you click on the input field, and slide out when one of the following occurs:
1. onblur
2. click on the check
3. click on the x

I have jquery loaded on the page as well.

There is an $id variable that gets the database's record id so I can assign it to the ids if needed.

Any assistance would be very much appreciated. Here is my code:

```
<div class="recordset">
    <div class="boxes">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="nameedit<?php echo $id; ?>" value="'.$name.'" />
        <input type="hidden" name="number" value="'.$number.'" />
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$id.'" />
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="recordbottom">
            <div class="playrecord">
                <embed ... (left blank) />
            </div>
            <div class="icons" id="icons<?php echo $id; ?>">
                <a href="records.php"><img src="x.png" width="18" /></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="check.png" width="18" /></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you have any other questions, please don't hesitate to ask.

EDIT:
I have tried about 25 - 30 different methods even simple CSS focus psuedos, the latest thing I have been trying is:

```
$('#nameedit').focus(function() {
    $('div.icons').show().bind('focusoutside clickoutside',function(e) {
        $(this).unbind('focusoutside clickoutside').fadeOut('medium');
    });
});
$('div.icons').hide();
```

This did not work out to well, another method I tried was:

well.... I used up all of my Ctrl-Z's so I cannot show anything definitive. I have search jquery, and googled many different tries, as well as about 20 or so from here.

PHP is my main programming language and JS is touch and go for me.

Comment: Point of detail : you really have multiple elements with same id ? If yes, this is a bad idea. Id should be unique. Use class instead.

Comment: Also keep in mind that there are 12 of those on each page. The sliding of the iconbar needs to be independent on each input field.

Comment: I can assign an number id to each one of them. Simply by putting: <input id="editname"<?php echo $id; ?>> same with the iconbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, by far I even made it better, now the question is? Is this the correct way to do it?

The $('editrecord') section will start by getting the value of the input and store it in a variable for later use (When someone clicks on the cancel image it will put the text back). Then show the iconbar with an animated slide in (The icon bar contains an X and a CHECK for cancel and save). Due to the player bar taking the entire length of each record, it will then hide with a slide out animation the player bar.

The $('.save_record') section will wait for the click on the CHECK, upon that click it will then send the records ID to the awaiting saverec.php (I just noticed that I have a GET with the ID there as well, I don't need that anymore since I am send via POST). I should probably put the iconbar hide and player bar show inside the success function, but either way it works now.

Finally the $('.cancel_record') section does 3 simple things, replaces the text back in the input box (Since they did cancel), hides the icons and shows the player bar.

Not too bad for my first taste of JavaScript with jQuery (in my opinion).

```
$('.editrecord').on('focus', function (){
    editname = $('#editname' + $(this).data('target')).val();
    $('#iconbar' + $(this).data('target')).show("slow", function() {});
    $('#playerrecord' + $(this).data('target')).hide("slow", function() {});
});

$('.save_record').on('click', function (){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "saverec.php?id=" + $(this).data('target'),
        data: jQuery('#saverecord' + $(this).data('target')).serialize(),
        success: function(data){
        }
    });
    $('#iconbar' + $(this).data('target')).hide("slow", function() {});
    $('#playerrecord' + $(this).data('target')).show("slow", function() {});
})

$('.cancel_record').on('click', function () {
    $('#editname' + $(this).data('target')).val(editname);
    $('#iconbar' + $(this).data('target')).hide("slow", function() {});
    $('#playerrecord' + $(this).data('target')).show("slow", function() {});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i made this:  http://fiddle.jshell.net/5GB4Z/

please note i referenced jquery 1.8.3, i think the 'on' method does not work with some older jquery versions.

Answer (score 0):

Well I guess with perseverance comes reward...

http://jsfiddle.net/AgGPh/

```
$('.editrecord').on('focus', function () {
    $('#icons' + $(this).data('target')).show("slow", function() {
        $( this ).prev().hide( "fast", arguments.callee );
    });
});
$('.editrecord').on('blur', function () {
    $('#icons' + $(this).data('target')).hide("slow", function() {
        $( this ).prev().hide( "fast", arguments.callee );
    });
});
```

Although it isn't pretty, but it is functional. I am not sure if this is the best method, although it works in fiddle, will try with my code and see what happens.

Thanks all,
Jeff

Comment: UPDATE - I have added a couple of records (minus a few graphics so it won't crash a browser) on the Fiddle. I have also updated it so it will remove the player bar and add the Save or Discard buttons. The input field is kind of hidden. If you click on the name (in this case it is "unknown"), you will be able to edit the names.